# Sending a cookie in a fetch request with Aurelia and Electron

Tags: cookies, electron, aurelia

## Aim

I have to access a remote web site through an Aurelia client. The solution should also work when wrapped with Electron. The request is done through a *http.fetch()*. This request has to be done multiple times with a different cookie set by the client.

## Issue

Various attempts to set the cookie have failed. It must be caused by some security layer within the client. Setting other headers with the same mechanisms works fine.

With no cookie header specified in the request, the service returns a *Set-Cookie* header which is internally handled correctly. Subsequent requests would send the received cookie as expected until the Electron client is restarted. This behaviour is as intended for most clients, but is not what I need for my specific problem.

## Attempted solutions

As far as I could track it, the same problem occurs in at least three different environments:

1. Electron
2. Firefox/Iceweasel
3. Chromium (with `chromium --disable-web-security --user-data-dir`)

I was running the index.html directly as "file://" as well as "http://" through an Apache web server. The accessed service URL always points to the same service in the Internet.

### Aurelia view-model (overview.js)

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Overview {

  constructor(http) {
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration()
        .withBaseUrl(this.url)
        .withDefaults({
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            // Default headers
            headers: {
              'X-fetch-default-header': 'fetch-default-header', 
              'Cookie': 'fetch-default-cookie=test'
            }
        });
    });
    this.http = http;
  }

  fetchRoot(nodeId){
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('X-my-header', 'my-header');
    myHeaders.append('Cookie', 'header-cookie=test');

    // Individual Headers Variant 1
    this.http.fetch('', 
      {credentials: 'include', headers: { 
          cookie: 'fetch-inline-cookie=test', 
          'X-fetch-inline-header':'fetch-inline-header' 
        }
    }).then(...);

    // Individual Headers Variant 2
    this.http.fetch('', 
      {credentials: 'include', headers: myHeaders})
      .then(...);

}
```

Alternatively, the same code has been tested with an additional `; path=/` directly behind the `key=value`.

### electron-cookies

With the package [electron-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-cookies), it is possible to access and manipulate the *document.cookie* property. The values set are even persistent across client restarts. Issues:

1. The cookies are not added to the request
2. *require* is not supported by browsers
3. The cookie parser seems to have issues when adding a path (unrelated, yet confusing)

The `fetchRoot(nodeId){}` was extended by the following code:

```
require('electron-cookies')
document.cookie = 'document-cookie=test';
```

### other packages

Attempts with other packages (e.g. a different [electron-cookies](https://github.com/exponentjs/electron-cookies) and the simple decorator fetch-cookie) seemed to suffer from the same security issue. At some point, the "set header" is not executed for cookies.

Comment: From the Fetch API documentation: "By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init option must be set)." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)